# How to convert JSON data to CSV format on the fly with out using csv file

Tags: php, json, csv

I am using PHP and converting the JSON data into the CSV format and later on read the same CSV file for further processing.

Below is my code that converts the JSON data in to the CSV format.

```
function LoadDataFromFile($file)
{

$json = file_get_contents($file);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$f = fopen('out.csv', 'w');
$firstLineKeys = false;
$keys = array();
//first collect keys
foreach($array as $line){
    foreach($line as $key => $value){
        if(!in_array($key, $keys))
            $keys[] = $key;
    }
}
$keyString = implode(",", $keys);
fwrite($f, "$keyString\n");
foreach ($array as $line)
{
    $outputArray = array();
    foreach($keys as $key){
        if(array_key_exists($key, $line)){
            $outputArray[] = str_replace(',', '', $line[$key]);;
        } else {
            $outputArray[] = "";
        }
    }
    $outputString = implode(",", $outputArray);
    fwrite($f, "$outputString\n");
}
fclose($f);

}
```

As we can see that, i am writing data into the "out.csv" file, and later on i am reading same CSV file and assign the value/ full contents of the same file line by line to $array variable, as shown below.

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('out.csv'));
```

Now, I want to directly assign the value of csv contents into the $array variable with out using the intermediate "out.csv" file.

Wondering what data structure should i use while converting JSON data to CSV format, and possible code changes required for "LoadDataFromFile" method?

Comment: Is your JSON always has the same format?

Comment: If yes please provide your json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can already convert the json into csv, then just append the output strings together assigned to a string variable instead of writing it to a file.  Or am I misunderstanding what you want?

Instead of:

```
fwrite($f, "$outputString\n");
```

you can put:

```
$csv .= $outputString;
```

And finish it with:

```
$array = explode("\n", $csv);
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. $csv .= $outputString;    $csv .="\n";